# Преобразовать значения в переменную

Tags: php, массивы

Нужно преобразовать значения в переменную

```
$res01 = '$g'.$in[$ra_k[0]].'x'.$in[$ra_k[1]];
```

Код:

```
  $in = range(77, 78);
  $ra_k = array_rand($in, 2);

  $g77x78='лялялляляля 111';
  $g78x77='лялялляляля 222';

  $res01 = '$g'.$in[$ra_k[0]].'x'.$in[$ra_k[1]];
  echo $res01;
```

Сейчас выводит в результате: `$g77x78`, но как сделать так, чтобы выводились **значения** из `$g77x78` или  `$g78x77`?

Comment: Использовать двойные кавычки.

Comment: тогда результат просто 
77x78

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *как сделать чтобы выводились значения из $g77x78 или $g78x77 ?*

Использовать экранирование **${**...**}**

```
$in = range(77, 78);
$ra_k = array_rand($in, 2);

$g77x78='лялялляляля 111';
$g78x77='лялялляляля 222';

$res01 = ${'g' . $in[$ra_k[0]] . 'x' . $in[$ra_k[1]]};
$res02 = ${'g' . $in[$ra_k[1]] . 'x' . $in[$ra_k[0]]};

echo $res01;
echo $res02;
```

---

Результат:

```
лялялляляля 111
лялялляляля 222
```

Comment: благодарю вас! и с НГ всех)

Comment: @z.RFRF спасибо, взаимно! )